# how to convert from string to integer an html element content on javascript side

Tags: javascript, html, button, type-conversion

```js
let counter = parseInt(document.getElementById("#integer").innerHTML)

let incbutton = document.querySelector("#increase")

incbutton.addEventListener("click", increase)

function increase() {
  counter += 1;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="integer">100</h1>
<button id="increase">Increase</button>
```

when ı try to convert to integer content of h1 tag increase button is not working. ı think because of h1 tag still string not integer. what is the mistake here? `your text`

Comment: [`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) needs to be called without the `#`, so `getElementById("integer")`. And then use [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) to convert the value to an int. And then assign the new value back to the `h1` element.

Comment: not sure how you do not know it is working because you are not showing the updated number anywhere in your code. But if you open up the developer tools in your browser it clearly shows an error. *{
  "message": "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'innerHTML')",*

Comment: Modifying `counter` does not change the content inside the `H1`.  They are two different things.

Answer (score 1):

simply update the counter value

```js
let counter = parseInt(document.getElementById("#integer").innerHTML)
let incbutton = document.querySelector("#increase")
incbutton.addEventListener("click", increase)
function increase() {
  counter += 1;
  incbutton.innerHTML = counter;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code converts the content of the element with the ID `integer` to an integer:

```
let counter = parseInt(document.getElementById("integer").innerHTML);
```

If the content of the element is not a valid integer, the parseInt() function will return NaN.

```
function increase() {
  counter += 1;
}
```

To update the content of the element with the ID `integer` with the new value of the counter, you can use the `innerHTML` property:

```
document.getElementById("integer").innerHTML = counter;
```

Here is a complete example of your code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Counter</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1><span id="integer">100</span></h1>
  <button id="increase">Increase</button>

  <script>
    let counter = parseInt(document.getElementById("integer").innerHTML);

    let incbutton = document.querySelector("#increase");

    incbutton.addEventListener("click", increase);

    function increase() {
      counter += 1;
      document.getElementById("integer").innerHTML = counter;
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: pls try to run in your computer is it working or not?

Comment: I have checked, you can also check

Answer (score 0):

The conversion to integer can also be done implicitly, by using the unary `+` operator. Also, when setting the text content of a DOM element you should use the `.textContent` instead of the `.innerHTML` property.

```js
const h1=document.getElementById("integer");

document.querySelector("#increase").addEventListener("click",()=>h1.textContent= +h1.textContent+1);
```

```html
<h1 id="integer">100</h1>
<button id="increase">Increase</button>
```